# Bzr and ubuntu one problem

Tags: ubuntu-one, bazaar

So I've got a folder with a programme I'm working on. I'm using bzr to keep revisions of it... and whenever I commit to bzr it seems to create conflicts... ooor

I'm editing the files in Matlab (ok it's not a real programme but whatever) and i'm not sure if this causes the problem.... Any suggestions?

Comment: could you be more specific about your problem? what exactly are the conflicts?

Comment: Can you post he exact errors you are getting?

Comment: Kindly post the exact error messages you get when you run `bzr commit`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not use Bzr but Mercurial and Git.

And as far as i know using both a sync service and a revision tool on the same folder may create problems especially if that folder is updated by on several computers running Ubuntu One (or any other file syncing service afaik).

I've been having a few issues with ubuntu one and mercurial and i think it has to do with the fact ubuntuone and the mercurial repository might not be in sync depending on the sequences of changes and commits. For instance I might update files on one computer and not commit them or get updated file from ubuntuone before or after i pull changes.

I think a second reference point (the bzr/mercurial/git) repository is enough to confuse ubuntuone.